# Possible to host on a custom subdomain with the top domain not managed by google?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I am building an application on Google App Engine to replace an existing solution. We already have a DNS for application.mycompany.com, so we will need to 'transfer' the DNS to App Engine when we switch.

I have read the documentation regarding custom domain names:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Is it correct that the entire DNS for mycompany.com needs to be managed by Google in this case? What if I already have a large DNS setup with another provider, and I can't migrate it, except for editing only the settings for application.mycompany.com? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be managed by google. You will just need to verify you own the domain by adding a TXT record (instruction included on verification process) then it will show up on the verified domains. Then add the subdomain on appengine then it will instruct you to cname it to ghs.googlehosted.com for the subdomain you want serving app engine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Faisal's answer in case you need SSL on this custom domain then you need to use a Google Apps Account. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl